# Are there any STL functions that wait that use wallclock time instead of "machine awake" time?

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to find a way to wait for a signal or maximum duration such that the duration is wallclock time instead of time the machine is spent awake.  For example, for the following order of events:

1. A wait() function is called for a maximum of 24 hours
2. 12 hours pass
3. Machine is put to sleep
4. 12 hours pass
5. Machine is woken up out of sleep

I would like the wait() call to return as soon as the process gets to run since 24 hours of wallclock time have passed.  I've tried using std::condition_variable::wait_until but that uses machine awake time.  I've also tried WaitForSingleObject() on windows and pthread_cond_timedwait() on mac to no avail.  I would prefer something cross-platform (e.g. in the STL) if possible.  As a backup, it looks like SetThreadpoolTimer() for windows and dispatch_after() (using dispatch_walltime()) on mac could work, but I would of course prefer a single implementation.  Does anybody know of one?

Thanks!

```
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    condition_variable cv;
    mutex m;
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(m);
    auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    cv_status result = cv.wait_until(lock, start + chrono::minutes(5));
    //put computer to sleep here for 5 minutes, should wake up immediately
    if (result == cv_status::timeout)
    {
        auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        chrono::duration<double> diff = end - start;
        cerr << "wait duration: " << diff.count() << " seconds\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `wait_until` takes a `time_point`. That's templated over the type of the clock. Wall time vs. CPU time depends on the clock you choose.

Comment: Trusting wallclock time is generally unreliable because the computer may lie about what the current time is (for example, the user can change the date of the computer to a date in the past). CPU time is a counter based on the cycle frequency of the CPU itself.

Comment: I think the only possible "standard" solution is to wait for some amount of time, wake up, check the system clock, then continue waiting if you didn't get signalled and it hasn't been 24 hours from the starting time. Anything else may or may not work depending on the platform and the implementation.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Interesting... is there a standard walltime clock in stl?  I did a bit of searching but couldn't find anything.

Comment: @jxh Unfortunately, I need to use wallclock time as tick count is not useful in this scenario.  We have something that expires every 24 hours.  If the computer is asleep, we need to know how long until that 24 hour mark.  Of course, we could listen for power events and go off of that, but in our design that's extremely weird.  It's a much better fit, architecture-wise, just to have an event API that is based on wall time instead of tick count.

Comment: Sometimes quantum jumps in time are part of normal operation, and will mess up your assumptions. Daylight savings time, for example.

Comment: @user450775: `steady_clock` seems to be the obvious choice here. "Objects of class steady_clock represent clocks for which [...] values of time_point advance at a steady rate relative to real time."

Comment: @JerryCoffin Thanks for the tip.  I gave it a shot but no dice - putting the computer to sleep in the middle of the wait didn't help.  Which is a shame because it's a clock that never goes backwards so time zones, daylight savings, and users changing their clock are already covered.